# Running a VB script from a batch file at the startup

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, startup

I have a batch file called 'bootstrap.bat' and its like this-

```
@echo OFF
@echo There is an error.

wscript errorMail.vbs

@echo Error Message sent
```

As you can see its calling a VB script which is just sending an email. The VB script is -

```
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "abcdmin@som.net"
objEmail.To = "som.sarkar@som.net"
objEmail.Subject = "Error: Generation of Final report failed" 
objEmail.Textbody = "There was an error in generating the Final report for the Test."
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
    "mailhost.som.net" 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
```

When I run the 'bootstrap.bat' manually from CMD, then the VB script is getting executed properly and the mail is getting sent. But I have a setup which will run the 'bootstrap.bat' at the startup but at that time it is not executing the VB script. I am not sure if I need to change any other things to get the VB script executed.

Comment: Probably (not tested) when the batch file runs from startup the default folder is not the folder where the batch file is stored, so, the vbscript file is not found. Try to use `wscript "%~dp0errorMail.vbs"` (or the full path to the script if it is in some other folder)

Comment: You also should use cscript than wscript. The difference is that wscript would open a messagebox on a call to "echo" where cscript writes to console.

Comment: MC ND, thank you, that worked. Can you please put your answer here, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use one file ;) instead of two (save as `.bat` or `.cmd`):

```
echo off
:sub echo(off):exit sub
set off=""'&set off=&cscript /nologo /e:vbscript "%~f0" %*&exit /b %errorlevel%
:end sub

Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "abcdmin@som.net"
objEmail.To = "som.sarkar@som.net"
objEmail.Subject = "Error: Generation of Final report failed" 
objEmail.Textbody = "There was an error in generating the Final report for the Test."
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
    "mailhost.som.net" 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send

WScript.Echo "Error Message sent"
```

There is one more [similar approach](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33882#p33882).